# What's timing dependency in context of virtualization?

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, computer-science, virtualization

In Popek and Goldberg virtualization requirements, Theorem 2 states:

> Theorem 2. A conventional third-generation computer is recursively virtualizable if
>
> (i) it is virtualizable and
>
> (ii) a VMM without any timing dependencies can be constructed for it.

What does timing dependencies mean?

Answer (score 0):

The performance observed in a VMM running on a real virtual machine and a VMM running on another VMM should be indistinguishable.
To say that a VMM has timing dependencies, it to say that certain instruction sequences could take longer to execute than others. Hence, a VMM without any timing dependencies is required.